# Cómo puedo obtener un ID auto incrementable que se crea al enviar datos por AJAX y PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin, id

Quiero los datos de id_comprador para mostrarlos en otra página. Así es como lo trato de obtener de la otra página

```
    <?php
include("conexionBD.php");
$id_comprador= $_GET['id_comprador'];

echo "<script> alert('$id_comprador')</script>";

$consulta = "SELECT nombre_completo, correo, ciudad, departamento, identificacion, direccion, 

detalles_extra, imagen, titulo, descripcion, tipo_id FROM `propiedad_comprada` inner join 

propiedad ON propiedad_comprada.id_propiedad = propiedad.id WHERE id_comprador='$id_comprador'";

$enlazamiento = mysqli_query($conexionBD, $consulta);

$info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($enlazamiento);
?>
```

Este formulario es de la página donde envío los datos.

```
<form class="formulario-pago" id="formulario-pago" method="POST">
            
            <div class="formulario">
                <h2>Datos personales</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre completo" id="nombre_completo" 
 name="nombre_completo"></input>
                <label>Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                <input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento"  name="fecha_nacimiento">
                <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
           
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: para que lo necesitas, lo necesitas antes o despues del insert???

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estas usando mysqli, necesitas llamar a la función [mysqli_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) , este retornará el ultimo id generado, según tu sesión.

#### Ejemplo de código

```
   mysqli_query($conexionBD, $consulta);
   $lastId = mysqli_insert_id($conexionBD);
```